# Just installed magento ... how do i set language?

Tags: language

I am new to magento but want to learn all ins and outs ;-)

I have downloaded version 1.9 and installed it on my vps (so i did not use the downloader file as that is 1.7 and no demo content)

I went through the installation and so far so good

During install i have set default country Netherlands etc.. as i am form the netherlands

So when viewing the store as is, i see dutch language used, but also some english (guess from pre-set cms pages as about us.

When i go to manage stores, i see 1 line

```
Website naam: Main Website (code base)
Winkel naam: Main Website Store (Wortelcategorie: Default Category)
Zie Winkel Naam: Default Store View (Code: default)
```

When i check online how to set up multi language i do not see the extra text between the brackets and only see this

```
Main Website      Main Website Store    Nederlands
Main Website      Main Website Store    English
```

How do i make sure i set this up correctly? Dutch is the default language and English is for now the only extra language

I hope someone can set me in the right direction as i can't find this in the manual

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Open your back-end Magento Connect and install this plugin for [DUTCH Translation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-official-dutch-translation.html)

**Step 2:** Grate now you have set up Dutch language pack.Bow Time to configure in backend. As you told that you have set `Netherlands` as default language then go to the `System >> Configuration >> General tab`.

**Step 3:** Now you can see `Current Configuration Scope:` in above left menu. just click on drop down and select `Nederlands` store. It will redirect to store view.

**Step 4:** now you can open `Local Options` Group Tab and select In Local `Dutch (Netherlands)`.

**Step 5:** Just click on `Save Config`.

**Step 6:** now at front-end you can see your whole site will be translated in `Dutch Language`.

This are just simple steps when you can set the Language Local.

Comment: Why are you suggesting he install an extension for a language pack?! Why are the official magento locale packs/translations down?!

Comment: please check when you install the magento then app/locale have nl_NL folder ?

Comment: oh, I know how to install locale packs - wondering why http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations is down

Comment: may be they are improving them so

Comment: It is well-known that the default language translations are not up to snuff.

Comment: @philwinkle Yes True Taht's y i suggest him. In most of my project we are using this